# Amcharts Angular gauge for server temprature

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, amcharts, gauge

If using Angular gauge Amcharts to check the server temperature. How to make randomValue function can be replaced with real value? In order for the temperature appointment to be in real time.
In this case I use the database

```
SELECT FROM TABLE WHERE server id='server-id'
```

And data will get is:

```
`30 | 2017-04-30 16:20:01 (value and date)`
```

We seat every 3 second the value will replace

How to put the value in order to change every 3 seconds? And the needle will move without refresh.

CHAR CODE are

```js
var gaugeChart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "type": "gauge",
  "theme": "light",
  "axes": [ {
    "axisThickness": 1,
    "axisAlpha": 0.2,
    "tickAlpha": 0.2,
    "valueInterval": 10,
    "bands": [ {
      "color": "#84b761",
      "endValue": 40,
      "startValue": 0
    }, {
      "color": "#fdd400",
      "endValue": 80,
      "startValue": 40
    }, {
      "color": "#cc4748",
      "endValue": 100,
      "innerRadius": "95%",
      "startValue": 80
    } ],
    "bottomText": "0",
    "bottomTextYOffset": -20,
    "endValue": 100
  } ],
  "arrows": [ {} ],
  "export": {
    "enabled": false
  }
} );

setInterval( randomValue, 3000 );

// set random value
function randomValue() {
  var value = Math.round( Math.random() * 90 );
  if ( gaugeChart ) {
    if ( gaugeChart.arrows ) {
      if ( gaugeChart.arrows[ 0 ] ) {
        if ( gaugeChart.arrows[ 0 ].setValue ) {
          gaugeChart.arrows[ 0 ].setValue( value );
          gaugeChart.axes[ 0 ].setBottomText( value + " " );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#chartdiv {
 width : 90%;
 height : 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/gauge.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You approach looks fine, this is how I do it using `$interval`. You will just have to replace the `random` routine with a call to a service that provides you data from the backend

```
var valuesArray = getData(); // gets an array of numbers from a service

$interval(function(passesValuesArray) {

    for (var i=0; i<vm.chart.arrows.length; i++) {
        vm.chart.arrows[i].setValue(arrowValue );
    }
}, 3000, 0 ,false, valuesArray);
```

`0` means it will loop forever (or until $interval will be canceled)

`false` means don't run the digest cycle after every run of the function, you will have to set it to true if you want other angular parts picking up the changed value

`valuesArray` is an array passed to the interval function as `passesValuesArray`.